# JQuery get element id from ajax loaded data

Tags: jquery, ajax, element

I load data from a PHP page with JQuery and it works fine. Now I want that when I click on one of these loaded elements an alert shows the id of the selected element. How can I do? If I put an element manually into the div "output" it works, but with the element created with $.ajax() it doesn't works.
Here is the code.

```
<input type="text" id="ricerca">
<div id="output" style="border: 1px solid #FF0000;"></div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Autocomplete
    $("#ricerca").keyup(function () {
        $(function () {
            var ricerca = $("#ricerca").val();
            $('#output').html("");
            if (ricerca.length > 0) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'dati.php',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        ricerca: ricerca
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        for (var i in data) {
                            var row = data[i];
                            var id = row[0];
                            var name = row[1];
                            $('#output').append("<a id='" + id + "' href='#'>" + name + "</a><br>");
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });

    // Show ID
    $('#output a').click(function () {
        alert(this.id);
    });
});
```

Comment: If the answer has helped you, do accept the answer and up-vote... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to do as follows for dynamically injected html:

```
$(document).on("click", "#output a", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Basically `#output` wont be there when you first load the page and hence you will need to bind the event to it.

So `.on` enables you to delegate the event to the handler.

**Helpful links:**

[What is DOM Event delegation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation)

[Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: Thank you very much, it works fine!
PS: You missed a parenthesis! ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `.on()` for registering click event of dynamically generated element

```
// Show ID

    $(document).on("click",'#output a',function() {
         alert(this.id);
    });
```

Answer (score -1):

It should be

```
alert($(this).attr("id"));
```