# Adding currency code to price in woocommerce

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm running a [currency switching widget](https://woocommerce.com/products/currency-converter-widget/) on my international woocommerce store. Im working on some jquery to prepend the country code to the price. So instead of the price displaying as $500, it will display as USD$500, and update when the user changes currency.

It works fine up until the click. `console.log ( newcurrency );` logs the correct country code on click, but the next line doesn't work.

```
$(function() {

    // Get current currency
    var currency = $( ".currency_switcher .active" ).text();

    // Add currency before price
    $( ".woocommerce-Price-amount" ).prepend( currency );

    //On click, update currency
    $( ".currency_switcher li a" ).click(function() {

        var newcurrency = $(this).text();

        console.log ( newcurrency );
        $( ".woocommerce-Price-amount" ).prepend( newcurrency );

    });

});
```

Any thoughts why that line isn't working?

Comment: My guess is that it is added by ajax or doesn't exist yet. You should check generated html (an option with dev tools in Firefox). Use something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/29279081/1004312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:** Add a custom currency / symbol

To add a custom currency in WooCommerce 2.0+, copy and paste this code in your theme `functions.php` file and swap out the currency code and symbol with your own.

After saving changes, it should be available from your WooCommerce settings.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
     $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
     return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break; {
}
 return $currency_symbol;
}
```

Code is not affected by updates if using a child theme.

**Solution 2:** [View this link](https://www.speakinginbytes.com/2014/04/currency-code-symbol-woocommerce/)